# How to define loading route for a nested route in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

This is my `router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.resource('articles', function() {
    this.route('article', { path: ':article_id' });
  });
});
```

When I transition from route

- `articles/1` to `articles/2` then `articles.loading` route is displayed.
- `articles.index` to `articles.index`, also `articles.loading` route is displayed.

I need to seperate these loading routes, so when I transition from

- `articles/1` to `articles/2`, `articles.article.loading` route should be displayed.
- `articles.index` to `articles.index`, `articles.loading` route should be displayed.

Using ember-cli:
`ember g route articles.loading` generates the `articles.loading` route.

I tried `ember g route articles/article/loading`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like generating nested routes just recently made it into ember-cli. And it looks like you have to use slashes as in `article/loading` not dots.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2748

Comment: I tried slashes too, I can make a `articles/loading` route. I can't make a `articles/article/loading` route. @KalmanHazins

Comment: It looks like you would just make a article/loading route and move it around yourself... I agree with you - it looks like it's missing from ember-cli...